# Coblat 25 - Angular 16 Support?

Tags: javascript, html, angular, cobalt

I am new to Cobalt so I built for Windows and created a very simple Angular 16 application with two components so I could test the routing. Each component has a button to route back to the other. The project was created with:

- ng create basic-angular
- ng generate component screen1
- ng generate component screen2
- Changed the body background to #dedede
- Added the routing by adding to app.module.ts:

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
...
    RouterModule.forRoot([
      {path: 'screen1', component: Screen1Component},
      {path: 'screen2', component: Screen2Component},

      {path: '', redirectTo: '/screen1', pathMatch: 'full'},
    ]),
```

- Added the screen1 html

```
<div>screen1 works!</div>
<button routerLink="/screen2">To Screen2</button>
```

- Added the screen2 html

```
<div>screen2 works!</div>
<button routerLink="/screen1">To Screen1</button>
```

I start the application using: `npm start` or `ng serve`

When I run the application within Cobalt I get the correct body background color and nothing else is displayed. I opened the remote web debugger and I don't see anything useful. The app renders fine through Chrome.

These are the screens within Chrome.

[image]

I then realized button elements were not supported so I create a new app using `ng new simple` and removed all the HTML in the app.component and added a simple div with a non-black color and background and some text to display. I run the app and it too does not work--works in Chrome.

I played some more and learned the script element of type "module" is not supported. Assuming this is correct, how can angular work at all?

Does Cobalt support Angular 16? I have seen previous posts suggesting older version of Angular were supported but no real details. Is there anything I can do to fix the problem?